# Export table structure information to Excel QGIS or MapInfo

Tags: data, fields-attributes, datastructure

I want to create a data dictionary of the tables of our primary layers. So I want a way to export the table structure to Excel. I don't need the actual data, I just want to know what columns are in each table and the data types for each column.

Our layers are in MapInfo, and I also have access to QGIS.

I can use the MapInfo Table Manager to export to a .met file, but when I copen that with Excel, the information is imported into one column - then requiring manual processing.

Comment: How did you want it structured? Each row is layer and columns are the fields?

Comment: Are these just normal tab files or are they in sql server?

Comment: I want the results for each layer to be in it's own worksheet (because there is other information that I want to collect and collate about the data). And they are normal .tab files - no sql servers involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply export it to MIF file type ([MapInfo's human-readable file interchange format](http://resource.mapinfo.com/static/files/document/1074660800077/interchange_file.pdf)). This creates a *.mif and a *.mid file. The .mif is what you need: after the header there's a section that lists the data COLUMNS by name with accompanying data type.

Comment: Thank you mtn.biker, that will work for me. There's still a lot of manual cutting and pasting to be done but it will do the job that I have now.